# Devise Admin works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, router

I'm creating an app using Ruby On Rails and Devise. I've created a User model and an Admin model and I have the app working fine when I run it locally but when I run it on heroku I'm having problems. The trouble is when I try to create a new admin I'm shown an error message that says "We're sorry, but something went wrong." I've already done a rake db:migrate and heroku run rake db:migrate. When I check heroku logs I see this:

```
2013-04-08T19:34:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/admins/sign_up" for 98.154.183.5 at 2013-04-08 19:34:49 +0000
2013-04-08T19:34:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Admins::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (431.3ms)
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for #<Admin:0x00000005207678>):
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 549ms
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     <%= f.error_notification %>
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: 
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <%= f.input :name %>
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <%= f.input :password %>
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:6:in `block in _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___3397140481100313441_30072880'
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___3397140481100313441_30072880'
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <%= f.input :email %>
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-08T19:34:50+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/admins/sign_up host=protected-cliffs-2228.herokuapp.com fwd="98.154.183.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=559ms status=500 bytes=643
```

For some reason unknown to me heroku is not linking to admins/registrations/new.html.erb but instead it's linking to devise/registrations/new.html.erb where it's reading the 'name' attribute that is showing up as an undefined method error.

My controllers/admins/registrations_controller.rb file looks like this:

```
class Admins::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

end
```

My routes.rb file looks like this:

```
MyFirstApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "users/show"

  devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :registrations => "admins/registrations", :sessions => "admins/sessions" } do
    get   "/admins/sign_up" => "admins/registrations#new"
    get   "/admins/sign_in" => "admins/sessions#new"
  end

  resources :posts


  devise_for :users
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show'


  root :to => 'pages#home'
  get 'about' => 'pages#about'

end
```

My development.rb file

```
MyFirstApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
end
```

My production.rb file

```
MyFirstApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  #In production, :host should be set to the actual host of your application.
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myfirstapp.heroku.com' }

  #Configuring Amazon S3 for Paperclip file uploads
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
end
```

My .gitignore file

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global

# Ignore bundler config
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*.log
/tmp
doc/
*.swp
*~
.project
.DS_Store
.idea

# Ignore Paperclip unloaded files
/public/system
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get! This is my first time creating an app so I apologize if my question is dumb but I'm stuck and I need some help!

Comment: Two questions: 1) are you sure you local installation indeed renders the `admins/registrations/new.html.erb` view and not `devise/registrations/new.html.erb`? and 2) it seems like you are subclassing Devise::RegistrationsController and adding nothing to your own controller (you don't have any methods), are you sure you need to subclass it?

Answer (score 0):

First check your gitrepo to make sure the file, or a related file, for some reason has been ignored.

And if that isn't the issue then just nuke the heroku project and start over.

Heroku has a special way of sometimes not creating new repos/projects correctly. The fail rate is pretty small, but you might have just rolled snake eyes.

If that doesn't work then post your production.rb and development.rb.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about that first part. How do I check to make sure the file, or a related file, has been ignored? I'm sorry I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: If your using Mac OSX go and download GitX. There are a number of GUIs for Git on windows and Ubuntu also. Use one of those to make sure the files you are wanting to show up are in the actually git repo. In other words, while looking at the repo with Gitx if your not seeing some files, you are going to need to do a 'git add .' Then try again. If that doesn't work make sure your .gitignore file isn't excluding them for some reason.

Comment: All the files are in my git repo. My .gitignore file isn't excluding them either. I updated my question to show my production.rb and development.rb files. I'm going to try starting a new heroku project like you suggested. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nothing in either of them that raise a reg flag for me... sorry I couldn't be more of a help...

Comment: I added my .gitignore file just incase I'm wrong about it not excluding them. Thank you

Comment: I created a new heroku project and ran git push heroku master. No luck im still having the same problem with the new heroku project :(